# Ext.device.Camera.capture doesn't accept width and height and quality

Tags: sencha-touch-2

So i have been using Sencha Touch 2 to create an application which can make a photo. After the photo has been made, the user can submit the picture to a server which accepts base64 as a string and then converts it to an actual jpg image. The problem i am facing is: No matter what parameters i give to the capture function, the photo that got send to the server is always a very small picture: 160x120.

The code i am using:

```js
var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Neem Foto',  cls: 'photowapp-button-action', 
    handler: function(){
    Ext.device.Camera.capture({

        source: 'camera',
        config: {
          scope: this,
          destination: 'data',
          encoding: 'jpg',
          width: 1000,
          height: 600
        },
        success: function(data) {

            base64 = data;

            var sendbutton = Ext.create('Ext.Button',{
              text: 'Verstuur', cls : 'photowapp-button-send', 
              handler : function() {
                panel.getParent().setMasked({
                                      xtype: 'loadmask',
                                      message : 'Foto versturen..'

                                  });
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                  url: 'http://fotoupload.mooieventjes.nl/v2/upload/test',
                  method: 'POST',
                  params: {
                    image : base64
                  },
                  callback : function(response) {
                     panel.getParent().unmask();
                  }
                });

              }
            });

        main.add(sendbutton);
        },



    });
```

Does anybody know why the capture function doesn't accept my parameter?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Sorry i did not come up with a solution. I moved on to native development because of better performance and better possibillities.